# Building gcloud api using bazel for windows

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-api, bazel

I want to add speech to text feature to my c++ application for windows, so I'm trying to build googleapi. I downloaded bazel and typed bazel //... in cmd and got error:

> - E:/dev/gapi/googleapis-master/WORKSPACE:116:1 ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository
>     'com_google_api_gax_java_properties':    Could not load dependencies
>     from properties file, error_code %s256 ERROR: no such package
>     '@com_google_api_gax_java_properties//': Could not load dependencies
>     from properties file, error_code %s256 ERROR: no such package
>     '@com_google_api_gax_java_properties//': Could not load dependencies
>     from properties file, error_code %s256 INFO: Elapsed time: 147.675s
>     INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0
>     packages loaded)

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I get the same error when trying to build Google APIs for using Firestore in my MAUI application (Windows)